# Python & subprocess - Open terminal session as user and execute one/two commands

Tags: python, subprocess

As much as I hate regurgitating questions, it's a necessary evil to achieve a result to the next issue I'll present.

Using python3, tkinter and the subprocess package, my goal is to write a control panel to start **and** stop different terminal windows with a specific set of commands to run applications/sessions of the [ROS application stack](http://www.ros.org/), including the core.

As such, the code would look like this per executable I wish to control:

```
class TestProc(object):
def __init__(self):
    pass

def start(self):
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-c", "'cd /path/to/executable/script.sh; ./script.sh'"])
    print("Process started.")

def stop(self):
    self.process.terminate()
    print("Process terminated.")
```

Currently, it is possible to start a terminal window and the assigned commands/processes, yet two issues persist:

- `gnome-terminal` is set to launch a terminal window, then relieve control to the processes inside; as such, I have no further control once it has started. A possible solution for this is to use `xterm` yet that poses a slew of other issues. I am required to have variables from the user's `.bashrc` and/or `export`
- Certain "global commands" eg. `cd` or `roslaunch` would be unavailable to the terminal sessions, perhaps due to the order of execution (eg. the commands are run before the bash profile is loaded) preventing any usable terminal at all

Thus, the question rings: How would I be able to start **and stop** a new terminal window that would run up to two commands/processes in the user environment?

Comment: cd is a shell built-in, not a command. Not quite sure what roslaunch is, but aliases are usually only available for interactive shell, not scripts.

Comment: it's an odd case regarding which executables can be called. roslaunch isn't an alias to my knowledge and this project is somewhat to replace aliases in the first place.

Comment: You really only need to use one of `executable="/bin/bash"`, `shell=True`, or `gnome-terminal -c`. By using all of these, you end up with three layers of shells, which will overcomplicate stuffs.

Comment: Actually, you seem to have have four layers of shell because your final executable is actually script.sh, which looks like a shell script.

Comment: Would indeed make things easier to remove the layers, adjusted that in the script proper. The shell script that needs be executed is unavoidable lest I have to include that in the python application itself.

Comment: Do you really need to start a new terminal window? I presume the Python program isn't a terminal program (IOW, is it a GUI program)? Or would it be acceptable to just run script.sh on the background, do you need to actually show output of script.sh, do you need to accept user input?

Comment: The python program is a GUI, yes. I do require the output of each program.
Disappointingly, I've found that running `xterm -e '/start_process.sh'` with the command in that shell script seems to have solved both issues at once.

Comment: That `cd` may not actually be necessary either. You can change the working directory of spawned script using `Popen(cwd="/path/to/executable/")`. Or you can let the terminal emulator to do it: `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/executable/`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple approaches you can take, the most flexible here is also the most complicated, so you'd want to consider whether you need to do it.

If you only need to show the output of the script, you can simply pipe the output to a file or to a named pipe. You can then capture that output by reading/tailing the file. This is simplest, as long as the script don't actually need to have any user interaction.

If you really only need to spawn a script that runs in the background, and you need to simulate user interaction but you don't actually need to accept actual user input, you can use `expect` approach (using the [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library).

If you need to actually allow the real user to interact with the program, then you have two approaches. First is that you can embed the [VTE widget](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-vte) into your application, this is the most seamless integration as it'll make the terminal look seamless with your application, however it's also the most heavy.

Another approach is to start gnome-terminal as you've done here, this necessarily spawns a new window.

If you need to both script some interaction while also allowing some user input, you can do this by spawning your script in a tmux session. Using `tmux send-keys` command to automate the moon interactive part, and then spawn a terminal emulator for users to interact with `tmux attach`. If you need to go back and forth between automated part and interactive part, you can combine this approach with expect.